# How to disable and enable icons based on zoom level in android google maps v2.?

Tags: android, icons, zooming, pinchzoom

I have so many icons on map.I want to disable some icons when I zoom out and I want to enable some icons when I zoom in. How can i achieve it? please give me some related links to achieve it.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I got it by using bellow code:

```
 private void listenOnCameraChange() {

googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {

            Set<Entry<Marker, MarkingInfo>> entrySetmarkers.entrySet();
            for (Entry<Marker, MarkingInfo> entry : entrySet) {
                Marker marker = entry.getKey();
                MarkingInfo markingInfo = entry.getValue();

                if (markingInfo.getZoomlevel() <= position.zoom) {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```